# Detect specific conditions database change

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a simple chat in my application using ASP.NET MVC 5 and SQL Server 2016.
Got the following table in database:

```
[dbo].[UserMessages](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserIdSender] [int] NOT NULL,
[UserIdReciever] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateSent] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[MessageText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[IsRead] [int] NOT NULL
```

So, when one user sends a message [UserIdSender] to another user [UserIdReciever], the second will see it when he opens his chat tab as the following request to db will be done:

```
public IQueryable<UserMessages> GetDialogByUserIds(int senderId, int recieverId)
    {
        return _msgRepo.GetAllQueryable(m => (m.UserIdSender == senderId && m.UserIdReciever == recieverId) ||
                                             (m.UserIdSender == recieverId && m.UserIdReciever == senderId));
    }
```

The question is to hold live chat, so when second user answers to first, the first one will see it immediately. So, I'm thinking about is there a way to create a specific event in sql when a specific table is changed
Something like this in sql:

```
if(UserMessages.IsChanged())
{
     event UserMessagesChanged();
}
```

Or is there any better way to notify user of incoming messages, to not sending a request every time database will be changed as there are many users and this event will fire every time any user sends a message?

Comment: Have a look [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the best way to solve it will be using a SignalR library. Read about what is a Hub and how does it work. And then put those lines in your hub class:

---

```
public class YourHub : Hub {
      public void MessageSender(int userId, string message)
        {
        //here you need to get the unique connectionId of a user
        //just make a query to the database for this
        Clients.Client(user.ConnectionId).sendMessage(message)

        }
}
```

---

Then on the client side:

```
 var hub = $.connection.yourHub;
        // Start Hub
  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        hub.client.sendMessage = function(message){
//here you just append the message for the user
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SqlServer on-premise, you can try to use SqlDependency to detect changes in the UserMessages table and trigger an event on .NET to manage the chat update and push the data to the browser side (using frameworks like SocketIO or SignalR to manage the server-browser communications). Biblio:

[Detecting Changes with SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency)

[Socket IO](https://socket.io/)

[Learn About ASP.NET SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

If you're using a cloud based architecture, you need to rethink your application layering and use the appropriate framework (for example, for Azure the SqlDependency is not available, and for detecting data changes you might choose to implement a Publish-Subscribe pattern using Azure Service Bus)